# Cleaning Netflix-style recommendation engine datasets

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, amazon-web-services

I am working on a portfolio project that deals with creating a Netflix-style recommendation engine for movies. This code is currently ran locally but I will need to upload it into Jupyter Notebooks and implement it with Amazon SageMaker. The .tsv files are imported from [IMDb Datasets](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/).

The code below is working code created by myself. Is there any room for improvement from an efficiency/cleanliness aspect?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

basics = pd.read_table('basics.tsv')
origin = pd.read_table('akas.tsv')
ratings = pd.read_table('ratings.tsv')

#setting 'basics' columns
basics.drop(basics.columns[[3,4,6,7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
basics.columns = ['tconst','type','title','year','genre']

#removing all non-movies from index
cond1 = basics['type'].isin(['movie','tvMovie'])

#setting new 'basics' variable
basics2 = basics[cond1]

#setting 'origin' columns
origin.drop(origin.columns[[1,2,5,6,7]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
origin.columns = ['tconst','region','language']

#removing non-english movies from index
cond2 = origin['region'].isin(['US','GB'])
cond3 = origin['language'] == 'en'

#setting new 'origin' variable
origin2 = origin[cond2 | cond3]

#setting 'ratings' columns
ratings.columns = ['tconst','rating','votecount']

#converting strings to integers
ratings.rating = pd.to_numeric(ratings.rating, errors='coerce').astype(np.int64)
ratings.votecount = pd.to_numeric(ratings.votecount, errors='coerce').astype(np.int64)

#setting new 'ratings' variable
ratings2 = ratings[(ratings['rating'] >= 5) & (ratings['votecount'] >= 50)]

#finalizing movie recommendation list
rcmd = basics2.merge(origin2,on='tconst').merge(ratings2,on='tconst')
rcmd.drop_duplicates(subset = 'tconst', keep ="first", inplace = True) 
print(rcmd)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your tsv files not have a heading row?

Comment: Oh, they do. So I'm not sure why you're setting your col names explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

### The usual

Use a PEP8 linter; move global code into functions; use type hints; use a `__main__` guard.

### Column use

```
basics.drop(basics.columns[[3,4,6,7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
basics.columns = ['tconst','type','title','year','genre']
```

really shouldn't be necessary. Use the `usecols` kwarg of `read_table` instead; the col names are a loose guess from the IMDB documentation:

```
basics = pd.read_table(
    'basics.tsv',
    usecols=(
        'tconst', 'titleType', 'primaryTitle', 'startYear', 'genres',
    ),
)
```

Comment: I set the columns for organization and aesthetic purposes. I did not like the default values provided, no other reason in particular.

Comment: Aesthetics is not a convincing argument to rename columns. You're hindering your code's ability to correspond with the IMDB documentation.